# DockPanel Suite: Alter Control+Tab order

Tags: dockpanel-suite

I'm trying to alter the order of the tabs which appear when using Control+Tab inside an application with several documents using DockPanel Suite.

To be exact, I'm willing to get a behaviour like Visual Studio. That is, if you have in example, documents 1, 2 and 3, being at document 1, pressing "Control+Tab" once brings you to document 2. If you now release the control key, and then press "Control+Tab" again, the document 1 pops. In general terms, VS stores the latest selected tabs and Control+Tab cycles through them in the order they were accessed previously

Is there a way to do so? (preferably without modifying the source code, but if needed I can try to change it)

thanks!

Comment: Without modifying the source code is almost impossible.

Comment: Actually I found a way several months ago :) but I forgot to post the answer. I used ProcessCmdKey in the main form in order to handle Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab myself, and returning true so that the key is not handled by DockPanel Suite. Then it's just a matter of handling the order of documents myself, and showing/hiding documents when Ctrl+Tab is pressed

Comment: you should post that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: thanks, not used to SO yet. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used ProcessCmdKey in the main form in order to handle Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab myself, and returning true so that the key is not handled by DockPanel Suite.
Then it's just a matter of handling the order of documents myself, and showing/hiding documents when Ctrl+Tab is pressed